# Mock rest data with mockito and generate api doc

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I want to create JUnit test for Rest api and generate api doc. I want to test this code:

Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
public class PaymentTransactionsController {

@Autowired
private PaymentTransactionRepository transactionRepository;

@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return transactionRepository
                .findById(Integer.parseInt(id))
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
public interface PaymentTransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<PaymentTransactions, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<PaymentTransactions> {

    Optional<PaymentTransactions> findById(Integer id);
}
```

Repository Impl:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("paymentTransactionService")
@Transactional
public class PaymentTransactionRepositoryImpl implements PaymentTransactionRepository {

@Override
    public Optional<PaymentTransactions> findById(Integer id) {
        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.id = :id";  
        TypedQuery<PaymentTransactions> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, PaymentTransactions.class).setParameter("id", id);
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = query.getResultList();
        return paymentTransactions.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(paymentTransactions.get(0));
    }
}
```

I tried to implement this JUnit5 test with mockito:

```
@ExtendWith({ RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class })
@SpringBootTest(classes = PaymentTransactionsController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PaymentTransactionRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    public final ManualRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new ManualRestDocumentation();

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    PaymentTransactionRepository target;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PaymentTransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        Optional<PaymentTransactions> optional = Optional.of(new PaymentTransactions());    

        when(transactionRepository.findById(Integer.parseInt("1"))).thenReturn(optional);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();

        PaymentTransactionRepository tnx = Mockito.mock(PaymentTransactionRepository.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(PaymentTransactionsController.class, "PaymentTransactionRepository", tnx);

      this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
              .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation)).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(target);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByIdFound() {
        Optional<PaymentTransactions> res = target.findById((int) 1);
        assertTrue(res.isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void uniqueTransactionIdLenght() {
        try {
            this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/transactions/1")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/xml;charset=UTF-8"))
                    .andDo(document("persons/get-by-id"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I get error for `when`:

```
The method when(Optional<PaymentTransactions>) is undefined for the type PaymentTransactionRepositoryIntegrationTest
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement mock test?

Comment: What is the full signature for the method `transactionRepository.findById(...)`?

Comment: I solved this issue by changing the mock code. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904887/java-lang-assertionerror-status-expected200-but-was404-in-junit-test/53905476#53905476