# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> in Junit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-restdocs

I want to create JUnit test for Rest api and generate api doc. I want to test this code:

Rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/transactions")
public class PaymentTransactionsController {

@Autowired
private PaymentTransactionRepository transactionRepository;

@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@PathVariable String id) {
        return transactionRepository
                .findById(Integer.parseInt(id))
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
public interface PaymentTransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<PaymentTransactions, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<PaymentTransactions> {

    Optional<PaymentTransactions> findById(Integer id);
}
```

I tried to implement this JUnit5 test with mockito:

```
@ExtendWith({ RestDocumentationExtension.class, SpringExtension.class })
@SpringBootTest(classes = PaymentTransactionsController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PaymentTransactionRepositoryIntegrationTest {
    .....
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PaymentTransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext,
              RestDocumentationContextProvider restDocumentation) {

        PaymentTransactions obj = new PaymentTransactions(1);

        Optional<PaymentTransactions> optional = Optional.of(obj);      

        PaymentTransactionRepository processor = Mockito.mock(PaymentTransactionRepository.class);
        Mockito.when(processor.findById(Integer.parseInt("1"))).thenReturn(optional);       

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
              .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
              .alwaysDo(document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint())))
              .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(target);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByIdFound() {
        Optional<PaymentTransactions> res = target.findById(Integer.parseInt("1"));
//        assertTrue(res.isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void indexExample() throws Exception {
            this.mockMvc.perform(get("/transactions").param("id", "1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/xml;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andDo(document("index-example", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()), links(linkWithRel("crud").description("The CRUD resource")), responseFields(subsectionWithPath("_links").description("Links to other resources")),
                    responseHeaders(headerWithName("Content-Type").description("The Content-Type of the payload, e.g. `application/hal+json`"))));
    }
}
```

I get error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
```

What his the proper way to to make GET request to the above code?
Probably I need to add response OK when message is send back?

Comment: status 404 means your request for "/transactions" is not found, can you use ` MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/transactions/{id}", 1) `...

Comment: I also tried this but I get `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Did you check whether your webApplicationContext is getting initialized and injected properly?

Comment: No, how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

hi in my case i needed @MockBean of controller and all services that is was autowireing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of @PostMapping and @GetMapping which caused same problem while @RequestMapping in  controller helped

Comment: This worked to me, why ???

Answer (score 0):

It's a path variable, so instead of using param value, please use path variable.

For MvcResult import, you can import `org.springframework.test.web.servlet`

```
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
```

...

```
given(target.findById(anyInt())).willReturn(Optional.of(new PaymentTransactions(1))).andReturn();

MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/transactions/1")
                .accept("application/xml;charset=UTF-8")).andReturn();

String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

this.mockMvc.perform(get("/transactions/1")
            .accept("application/xml;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("index-example", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()), links(linkWithRel("crud").description("The CRUD resource")), responseFields(subsectionWithPath("_links").description("Links to other resources")),
                responseHeaders(headerWithName("Content-Type").description("The Content-Type of the payload, e.g. `application/hal+json`"))));
```

Comment: I get `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>` at this line `.andExpect(status().isOk())` Any idea why?

Comment: Can you please try add below line before `this.mockMvc.perform`     `given(target.findById(anyInt())).willReturn(Optional.of(new PaymentTransactions(1)));`
and see if this works?

Comment: @PeterPenzov sure, please try it.

Comment: I tried it but I get again error 404. Any idea how to debug it?

Comment: yea, you can definitely. I updated the answer, please look at it.

Comment: Do you know what maven dependencies I have to import for andReturn();?

Comment: By the wya I use JUnit 5 looks like your code is for JUnit 4?

Comment: you can import `import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;` you can get the library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test.

Comment: With cast I managed to implement it but I get compilation error. This code is probably for JUnit 4?

Comment: Yea, It’s in jUnit 4, but idea is you can printout, debug results using MvcResult and other helpful methods.

Comment: one example I found using jUnit 5 is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727758/spring-5-with-junit-5-mockito-controller-method-returns-null, but it should be same. Can you post the compilation error message too? and your url should be like /transactions/1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this..

```
public class PaymentTransactionsControllerTest {

private MockMvc mvc;

@InjectMocks
PaymentTransactionsController paymentTransactionsController;

@MockBean
private PaymentTransactionRepository processor;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(paymentTransactionsController).build();
}

@Test
public void indexExample() throws Exception {

    PaymentTransactions obj = new PaymentTransactions(1);
    Optional<PaymentTransactions> optional = Optional.of(obj);  

    Mockito.when(processor.findById(Integer.parseInt("1"))).thenReturn(optional); 

    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/transactions/{id}", 1))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    Assert.assertNotNull(result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
}
}
```

Comment: I get NPE at this line `MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/transactions/{id}", 1))`

Comment: can you replace by this code in your setup, i think PaymentTransactionsController is not injected in your test so you are getting NPE `@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PaymentTransactionRepository()).build();
}`

Comment: i have small demo for unit test in my git repo... it can help you.. https://github.com/prameshbhattarai/spring-boot-demo

Comment: I get again NPE at the same line.

Comment: can you provide me the stack trace for your exception... also did you check my repo..

Comment: Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/06b7XsFH I will test your code example today.